# range() returns the word itself

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python 3.6

when I use the range function in Python console, it didn't return an array, instead it shows the wording itself:

range(1, 5)

> > > range(1,5)

print(range(1,5))

> > > range(1,5)

How can I show the array?

Answer (score 1):

The `range()` function in Python 3 returns an iterator, something you can iterate on, so you can use it as:

`for x in range(1, 5):
    print(x)`

This iterator returns one value at a time, so it can be more memory efficient.

If you want to get a list, you can use this code:

`list(range(1,3))`